# How to set spinner dropdown list position in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to place a dropdown list on the right. Can I do this in a [standard spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is a `Spinner`? I think this can be implemented by  `PopUpWindow` .

Answer (score 0):

I think Image represented is PopUp menu, To achieve the same see the code below,

To define popup menu, we need to create a new folder menu inside of our project resource directory (res/menu/) and add a new XML (popup_menu.xml) file to build the menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/first_item"
        android:title="first" />
    <item android:id="@+id/second_item"
        android:title="second" />
    <item android:id="@+id/third_item"
        android:title="third" />
</menu>
```

In your Activity,

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v, Gravity.RIGHT);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Now Override onMenuItemClick to provide functions to each item.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.first_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
            case R.id.second_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
            case R.id.third_item:
                // do your code
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like what I need, but I can not display the menu on the right. I already tried to do it in a new clear project (API 19+) but it seems gravity in popup menu constructor not working as expected. Also I've tried various root view and anchor views but to no avail.

Comment: This might help you, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html